# Get Records in group by highest id in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

There is a database relation where some records are combined by a group_id.

| id | group_id | name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row23 | Alex | ... |
| 2 | row15 | Mike | ... |
| 3 | row15 | Andy | ... |
| 4 | row16 | Anna | ... |
| 5 | row23 | Max | ... |
| 6 | row15 | Lisa | ... |

I need to group all records by its group_id and get records from each group with the highest id.

One approach which works but is not ideal for performance on data with many records could be:

```rb
def self.newest_records
  all.group_by(&:group_id).map { |_id, records| records.max_by(&:id) }.flatten.compact
end
```

The following approach also works, but I think there's another way to get the records directly without the id lookup.

```rb
def self.newest_records
  ids = select(:id, :group_id).group(:group_id).pluck(Arel.sql('max(records.id)')) # get highest id of group
  Record.where(id: ids)
end
```

This will generate a huge SQL Command, which I think is not the best way.

```sql
SELECT "records".* FROM "records" INNER JOIN "relation" ON "records"."relation_id" = "relations"."id" WHERE "relations"."master_id" = 1 AND "records"."id" IN (1, 4, 5, 8, 10, 2, 3, 10000 others)
```

What might be a better solution to get the records by the highest id of a group directly without selecting them in the surrounding `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with this command

```rb
Record.select('DISTINCT ON ("group_id") records.*').order(:group_id, 'records.id DESC')
```

Now I get directly the Records with the highest `id` of each group.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```rb
Record.group(:group_id).maximum(:id)
```

And the output is

```rb
{
    'row23' => 5,
    'row15' => 3,
    'row16' => 4
}
```

Update:

Having `record` ids you can use them in other query

```rb
Record.where(id: Record.group(:group_id).maximum(:id).values)
```

Comment: Yeah, but I was asking to get the records not a list of those ids.

Comment: Check my update. In Postgres you can't do this is one query because Postgres requires all selecting fields to be present in GROUP BY

Comment: It's PostgreSQL. Thanks for the update. I'll give it a try

Comment: But I thought, there is a possibility to get rid of the Record.where(id: [10000 ids])